# JTable not losing focus on ENTER and TAB

Tags: java, swing, focus, jtable, focusmanager

```
table.changeSelection(table.getRowCount()-1, 3, false, false);
```

after setting the cell selection like above, the cell is selected and if i enter the value in to the cell, the cell goes to editing mode. But, after the value is entered, if i press ENTER or TAB key the cell is still in editing mode. If i press some where on other component then only the cell closes editor mode.

how to solve this?

Comment: Any chance you could include [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> after setting the cell selection like above, the cell is selected and if i enter the value in to the cell, the cell goes to editing mode

1. for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) demonstraded your issue about `table.changeSelection` and `TableCellEditor`
2. have to override `stopCellEditing`

depends of your TableCellEditor

```
table.putClientProperty("terminateEditOnFocusLost", Boolean.TRUE);
```

or

```
@Override
public boolean stopCellEditing() {// @see CellEditor#stopCellEditing()
    fireEditingStopped();
    return true;
}
```